# DNS in windows server 2012 R2 is incorrectly configured

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2

I originally setup my internal DNS server for active directory. I just followed a pretty simple tutorial (i believe at https://www.petri.com/install-active-directory-windows-server-2012-manager). Everything has worked for some time (years). The only recent problem i've had is one of my machines had an incorrect 'A' record in DNS which i had to go delete. It was the reason i couldn't remote desktop to the specific machine. After i deleted the 'A' Record it fixed the issue.

After i originally set DNS up for AD the only small thing i changed was i added two forwarders (opendns) so internal DNS could forward requests not found on internal machines to the internet.

DHCP is coming from the router. I setup the router so it would return the following IP addresses to all clients:

```
nameserver1: 192.164.0.1 (internal dns server)  
nameserver2: 208.67.222.222 (opendns)  
nameserver3: 208.67.220.220 (opendns)
```

Why did i setup nameserver2 & 3? Because i want all clients to be able to get to the internet even if the internal DNS server is down (its happened before).

Ok so my issue is after i installed ubuntu it was unable to resolve any machine names (even fully qualified) on the internal network. So pinging either machine1 or machine1.mydomain.com would both fail. Somone on the ubuntu forums helped me out some by pointing out that i needed to add a domain to dhcp. After i added my domain to dhcp then i could ping machine1 but still couldn't couldn't ping machine1.mydomain.com. The person on the ubuntu forums of course doesn't know windows dns that well (he only knew bind) so i'm helping someone here can help me determine what i have setup wrong.

Here is the original [Thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2287596&p=13327603#post13327603) on the ubuntu forums. Just as a FYI. I also have a Mac on the internal network and if i use the fully qualified name then i'm able to resolve internal machines.

Comment: Don't use ping to test name resolution, use nslookup or dig. Don't assign non-AD DNS servers to AD clients.

Comment: I was just using ping because i couldn't  remote desktop to those servers. So its not only ping thats not working the remote desktop client i'm using isn't working either. If you look at the thread i referenced i used both nslookup & dig. Are you talking about the nameserver2 & 3 when you say dont' assign non-ad dns servers to ad clients? Why?